# css w3-half same height issue

Tags: html, css, height

I searched the forums but didn't find anything that helps my problem.

How can I make one half-screen size the same as the other half with `CSS`? Plus both halves should fill the whole screen in height at the beginning too.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8BzF.png)

Snippet:

```css
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

.w3-bar .w3-button {
  padding: 16px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
}

.img {
  border: none;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-center">
  <div class="w3-row">
    <div class="w3-half w3-container w3-pink">
      <p>Some Text</p>
      <div class="w3-half w3-container">
        <p>Pics and some Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the heights or widths of the parents elements in order to have a working percentage for your `w3-half` class.

In your code, one `w3-half` element is a child of the other. They better be siblings if you want both of them to be the same width (i.e. 50% of parent).

Here is a snippet, I hope that will help you:

```css
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

.w3-center,
.w3-row {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 4px 0;
}

.w3-half {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 4px 0;
}

.w3-bar .w3-button {
  padding: 16px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
}

.img {
  border: none;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
}


/* This below only for test purpose */

.w3-center {
  background: red;
}

.w3-row {
  background: green;
}

.w3-half {
  background: blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-center">
  <div class="w3-row">
    <div class="w3-half w3-container w3-pink">
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </div><div class="w3-half w3-container">
      <p>Pics and some Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: updated after comment.

Comment: Hi, Many Thanks for your help. There was a slight misunderstanding though. I wanted them side by side and not below each other :) With your code i will try to rework it.

Comment: Hi thanks again. I played around a bit and found an solution with only 1 variable to change. I declared them as cells. :)